# Reorder parameters in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, webstorm

In ReSharper I used to have a `Ctrl+Alt+Shift+Left arrow` bound to reordering values. It would take whatever paramater/value/argument I had selected and move it one to the right. For example:

```
first, second third
```

would become

```
first, third, second
```

I've since switched to WebStorm and don't have my old ReSharper settings and can't find any such similar bind. Is this possible in WebStorm? Is there any macro functionality in WebStorm so that I could implement it myself?

It's worth noting that there is a `Move Element Left`, however this doesn't appear to do anything in JS files.

### Edit

There is macro functionality, however the only way to implement it would be to:

> select the current word -> cut -> delete the proceeding comma -> move the cursor one word left -> paste -> add comma

This results in a lot of undo's if I decided I don't want that.

Comment: Well .. there are `Code | Move Element Left/Right` actions in 2016.1 (at least in IntelliJ IDEA -- https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2016/01/intellij-idea-16-eap-improves-editor-and-vcs-integration/ , although they are available in menu in PhpStorm 2016.2 as well). I do not think it will *cycle* your parameters .. but it can move them for sure.

Comment: Also -- there is `Refactor | Change Signature` -- you can reorder parameters there (should be invoked on function definition) and it should be applied to all function calls found by IDE.

Comment: Most likely that "Move Element Left/Right" is not yet implemented for other languages (quite often all this functionality requires language-specific implementation)... Worth creating Feature ticket at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently the only way to reorder parameters is `Refactor | Change signature`. If you miss the other way to change parameters order, please file  a feature request to youtrack. See also https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-2175